# Autobahn symmetric RPC

Tags: autobahn

I am trying to use symmetric RPC in Autobahn.

from autobahn.wamp.protocol import exportPRC, WampClientFactory, WampClientProtocol

But, I got this error:

> > > from autobahn.wamp.protocol import  exportRPC, WampClientFactory, WampClientProtocol
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ImportError: cannot import name exportRPCl

I followed http://autobahn.ws/python/installation.html, but could not get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems from v0.9. Sample of symmetric rpc can not be found. WAMP1 also can not be found. I installed v0.10. That's why is has this problem.